# Using Multiple Branch Cuts in a Contour Integral

Tags: complex-integration, branch-cuts

I have the integral

$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\!\frac{x^{1/2}}{\left(x^3+a^3\right)^{1/2}\left(2x^3+a^3\right)^{1/6}}\,\mathrm dx$$

which I am trying to integrate using complex integration.  I know that each of the three terms has a fractional exponent, so I'd expect I need multiple branch cuts when I'm defining my contour.  I have easily found the singularities (note $a\in [0,\infty)$ here).  Most examples I've found online demonstrate how to solve for a branch cut with $\sqrt{x}$ but nothing like this.

**Here's my attempt:**  I think I have seven branch points (not including those at infinity), since when the denominator is factored I end up with a total of six terms in the denominator and one term in the numerator, each with a fractional exponent.  One approach would be to draw the branch cut from each branch point to infinity, radially outward.  Another approach would be to draw a branch cut from the origin to each of the other six branch points, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Isn't that trivial that the integral is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ times some constant? The only problem is that such a constant is quite ugly, given by $$\frac{48\cdot 2^{1/6} \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right) \pi^2}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{12}\right)^2 \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}.$$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - how did you find this?

Comment: Just replace $x$ with $az$, then compute the resulting integral (the constant) by exploiting Laplace transforms.

Comment: Of course! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Letting $x=au,$ and $t=\dfrac1{1+u^3}~,$ we are ultimately left with proving that $$\int_0^1(1-t)^{-1/2}~t^{2k-1}~(2-t)^{-2k}~dt ~=~ \frac12~B\bigg(k,~\frac12\bigg),$$ where *B* is the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).